# Dynamically limit start date using Datepicker in jQuery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Following is my script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var minDate = new Date();
            $("#depart").datepicker({
                showAnim: 'drop',
                numberOfMonth: 1,
                minDate: minDate,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onClose: function(selectedDate){
                    $('#return').datepicker("option", "minDate","selectedDate")
                }
            });

            $("#return").datepicker({
                showAnim: 'drop',
                numberOfMonth: 1,
                minDate: minDate,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                onClose: function(selectedDate){
                    $('#depart').datepicker("option", "minDate","selectedDate")
                }
            });         
        });
  </script>
```

And following is my html code

```
Depart Date: <input type="text" name="depart" id="depart" placeholder="depart date"/>
Return Date: <input type="text" name="return" id="return" placeholder="return date"/>
<input type="submit" />
```

Using `$("#depart").datepicker()` all the dates before current day in being disabled. Perfect.

Whereas for `$("#return").datepicker()` the `minDate` should be the depart date selected which is not happening as per my case.

Can anyone tell me my mistake?

Comment: You're passing string literal `"selectedDate"` rather than the variable `selectedDate`:  `$('#return').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate)`

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m ...! Its working now.

Comment: You're welcome.  Voted close as a typo as it's unlikely to help anyone in the future.  Glad to hear you got it to work.